# Angular 2 how to get a sub-path from the URL

Tags: angular

I have a textbook route like this:

```
{ path: "browse/:id", component: BrowseComponent },
```

What I want to do is to be able to get the trailing path part when the activated route is something like

```
http://localhost:4200/browse/a/b/c/d
```

So id would be set to "a/b/c/d".   Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Get the path from `this.router.url`(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#url-anchor) then parse the path using something like slice or substring

Comment: How do I code a route that will match the URL?   for example the path "browse/:id" in my example will not match "/browse/x/y/z.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UrlMatcher by providing matcher key for a Route. Unfortunately it's undocumented for now, so you may need to check the source of router/src/config.ts:

````
/**
 * @whatItDoes Represents the results of the URL matching.
 *
 * * `consumed` is an array of the consumed URL segments.
 * * `posParams` is a map of positional parameters.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export type UrlMatchResult = {
  consumed: UrlSegment[]; posParams?: {[name: string]: UrlSegment};
};

/**
 * @whatItDoes A function matching URLs
 *
 * @description
 *
 * A custom URL matcher can be provided when a combination of `path` and `pathMatch` isn't
 * expressive enough.
 *
 * For instance, the following matcher matches html files.
 *
 * ```
 * function htmlFiles(url: UrlSegment[]) {
 *  return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.endsWith('.html') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
 * }
 *
 * const routes = [{ matcher: htmlFiles, component: HtmlCmp }];
 * ```
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export type UrlMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) =>
UrlMatchResult;
````

This basically allows you to write a function that can do any kind of matching, including regular expressions.

It's still experimental, so there aren't many examples around, but github/matanshukry has kindly provided a gist example of ComplexUrlMatcher. It should give you an idea how to implement one that suits your needs (sadly there's no license, so you can't use it as-is).

Link for more info

http://blog.devcross.net/2016/03/25/angular-2-router-and-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

Late to answer but If you still have the same issue here's how I solved the same problem..

This is my route

```
{
    path: 'browse',
    component: ParentBrowseComponent,
    children : [{
        path: '**',
        component: BrowseComponent
    }]
}
```

I have defined `browse` as parent route and defined a `**` child route to it. Child are using `BrowseComponent` as component and Parent is using `ParentBrowseComponent`.

IN my  BrowseComponent constructor I am detecting changes in url using

```
_router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val);
    if(val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        var url = this._router.url;
        //do anything with url
    }
});
```

imported routes like this

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

This will get me the current route

For example in case of this route

> http://localhost/browse/a/b/c/d

it will give me

> /browse/a/b/c/d

You can easily manipulate this url for your use.

Wondering what does your parent compoenent holds, just one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Yes everything is under one router-outlet element.  Conventional coding is to use URL parameters (like ?xx=abc) but I look forward to a world with only "clean" URLs.   Thanks for your tip.